# Why getting "Invalid JSON" added to my custom error message

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

Invalid JSON:

```
Error 1 : Non-MDX format found.
```

Why I am getting the Invalid JSON with my custom error message.

My code is given bellow:

```
$('#btnCreateView').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Mdx")',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        dataType: "json",

        success: function (result) {
            alert("View Created Successfuly");
            window.location = result.link;

        },
        error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#ErrorMessageField').html(errorThrown);
        }

    });
})
```

Comment: Could you show the code of your `Create` controller action?

Comment: [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(ImsViewCube imsViewCube)
        {
            try
            {
              var url = new UrlHelper(ControllerContext.RequestContext);
              var link = url.Action("Index",new{viewId = imsViewCube.ViewId});
              return Json(new { link });
            }
            catch (ParserException e)
            {
                errorList = e.GetErrorMessages();
                ViewBag.MessageList = errorList;
                return PartialView("Fail");
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

In your controller action you seem to be returning a partial view:

```
return PartialView("Fail");
```

but in your AJAX request you inidicated

```
dataType: "json",
```

Obviously this is inconsistent. When jQuery attempts to parse the string returned from your controller action back into javascript object it fails because you are not sending JSON, you are sending partial HTML.

Comment: You can't. This doesn't make any sense. A partial view means partial HTML markup. JSON is an entirely different thing.